# Python: Peewee Update Query is not working

Tags: python, sqlite, peewee

I use pewee and the following queries:

```
 for row in Group.select():
    group_data = process_group(row.link)
    Group.update(name=group_data[0], type=group_data[1], member=group_data[2]).where(Group.id==1)

for row in Group.select():
    group_data = processl_group(row.link)
    Group.update(name=group_data[0], type=group_data[1], member=group_data[2]).where(Group.link==row.link)
```

Group - is the table name ;
name,type,member,link - are the columns
database - sqllite

I tested separately if group_data values exit and are ok, now issue
Group.id= 1 ; exist

I have no idea what is the problem. Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to call `.execute()` at the end of your query:

```
for row in Group.select():
    group_data = process_group(row.link)
    (Group
     .update(name=group_data[0], type=group_data[1], member=group_data[2])
     .where(Group.id==1)
     .execute()) # Added .execute
```

Comment: You may want to add that the need of `execute` to [this](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/query_examples.html?highlight=update#update-some-existing-data) as I spent an hour checking the documentation and googling what was wrong until I found this answer.

Comment: Sorry, I can see how that would be super confusing: https://github.com/coleifer/peewee/commit/d67890db547e221a8dce07b67299ee0efdf7e420